# Loading files from web

Tags: android, download

I have the following situation:
I have files under raw directory. I use them to load them to textview.
I want user to load files from web to be used the same way.

Is it possible? Or do I need to load them to SD? 
If so - on the SD - how do I prevent reading\copy of these files (in raw directory it is not reachable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load files to the SD card, to internal storage, an SQLite data base, or as a Preferences object. This is discussed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html), including security aspects.

What you cannot do is dynamically add to the resources or assets folder that ships with your app.